# Getting auto.arima working

Tags: r, time-series

Pls can someone help me with how to get auto.arima working in my r. what package should i download? I tried to download auto.arima package but it was not available.

Answer (score 0):

try this

> install.packages("forecast")
>
> library(forecast)

then try using the auto.arima function